# segue adds a navigation to the view

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have added a `NavigationBar` to View2 with a "Back" item and then I ctrl-dragged from this item to View1 to add a `segue` (a `show` segue). Now whenever "Back" is used to navigate to View1, I get a navigation bar (with an item "back") to this view (View1). I only want a navigation bar to View2, not View1. I can always hide View1's `NavigationBar` programmatically but I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide navigation Bar for View1 inside ViewWillAppear and unhide while going to viewWillDisappear:

**View1:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:true];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:false];
}
```

**View2:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:false];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:true];
}
```

Any one of class function you can use, either view1 functions or view2 functions to hide and unhide navigation bar while switching controller.